# How to list users by custom field?

Tags: shortcode, users, user-meta

I have a custom user field in the standard database, called `company`.
I want to output on to a page the usermeta info only of users whose `company` matches `Widgets Inc` ...

How do I do that?

What I'd really like to be able to do is avoid putting this in a page template and instead create a shortcode to list user info, with functionality to limit by field attribute - ie. `{listusers company="Widgets Inc"}`

But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch users with certain meta field, you can use `WP_User_Query` class. Check [codex manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) for it.

So you can create a custom shortcode like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'listusers', 'wpse8170_listusers' );
function wpse8170_listusers( $atts, $content = '' ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'company' => false ), $atts );

    if ( empty( $atts['company'] ) ) return $content;

    $query = new WP_User_Query( array(
        'meta_key' => 'company', 
        'meta_value' => $atts['company'],
    ) );

    ob_start();

    // render your users list here

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene. But that produces no output on my end. Should I be inserting something beneath "// render your users list here"?

Comment: yes, echo your HTML code there